# React Dist Without Server, Node or Http-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, redux

I have a simple React App that's using webpack to make a production dist, but when I open the index.html, it's nothing but a blank page.
I tried meddling with webpack configs, searching the reason it may be, but I utterly failed.

I need to make a dist and be able to run the app with just the static files, no server, is that possible? Or do I really need a http server or node to serve files or modules even after compiling everything?

webpack.config.js

```js
'use strict';

/* eslint no-console: "off" */
const webpackConfigs = require('./conf/webpack');
const defaultConfig = 'dev';

module.exports = (configName) => {

  // If there was no configuration give, assume default
  const requestedConfig = configName || defaultConfig;

  // Return a new instance of the webpack config
  // or the default one if it cannot be found.
  let LoadedConfig = defaultConfig;

  if (webpackConfigs[requestedConfig] !== undefined) {
    LoadedConfig = webpackConfigs[requestedConfig];
  } else {
    console.warn(`
      Provided environment "${configName}" was not found.
      Please use one of the following ones:
      ${Object.keys(webpackConfigs).join(' ')}
    `);
    LoadedConfig = webpackConfigs[defaultConfig];
  }

  const loadedInstance = new LoadedConfig();

  // Set the global environment
  process.env.NODE_ENV = loadedInstance.env;

  return loadedInstance.config;
};
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the whole source code. It may be not a problem with webpack at all. The easiest way to get things running is to use `create-react-app` and then just adjust with the project you already have. You will have a production-ready static bundle.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to host your app on S3 (and others) :

https://medium.com/@omgwtfmarc/deploying-create-react-app-to-s3-or-cloudfront-48dae4ce0af

For different deployment strategies you could have look at the [CRA readme](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment)

Comment: The problem being my index.html doesn't show my app, it's blank after running the dist. Doesn't seem like the app.js is doing anything but being there.

Comment: If you want to try locally you can do : `serve -s dist` [see](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#static-server)